# Yield curve sorting in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataset from FedYieldCurve

```
data(FedYieldCurve)
```

which looks as follows but with more periods

```
            R_3M  R_6M  R_1Y  R_2Y  R_3Y  R_5Y  R_7Y R_10Y
1981-12-31 12.92 13.90 14.32 14.57 14.64 14.65 14.67 14.59
1982-01-31 14.28 14.81 14.73 14.82 14.73 14.54 14.46 14.43
1982-02-28 13.31 13.83 13.95 14.19 14.13 13.98 13.93 13.86
1982-03-31 13.34 13.87 13.98 14.20 14.18 14.00 13.94 13.87
1982-04-30 12.71 13.13 13.34 13.78 13.77 13.75 13.74 13.62
1982-05-31 13.08 13.76 14.07 14.47 14.48 14.43 14.47 14.30
```

where I want to sort the dates by the types of yield curves (normal, inverse or humped).

The first question is how can I check for the curve types?
One possibility is to  use `sort` but I really do not know what arguments to use here. Another way I could imagine is to use iterated if-functions, but this seems to be more difficult.

The second question after identifying the typ of the curve how can I sort them. 
Here I thought to use a for loop

```
for (i in 1:ncol(FedYieldCurve))
{
  normal <- sort(FedYieldCurve)
  inverse<- sort(FedYieldCurve)
  humped<- (FedYieldCurve-normal-inverse) 
  list <- rbind(normal, inverse, humped)
}
```

Comment: This left me scratching my head. You don't give us the definition of "normal, inverse or humped". So, how is anyone without your domain knowledge supposed to help you?

Comment: In my case I think normal is when the yields are increasing (from R_3m to R_10Y), inverse when they are descending (from R_3m to R_10Y) and all others are humped. This is why I thought it may be done if if statement.

Comment: @Sogoman Based on your definition, none of the dates look `normal` or `inverse` in the example you showed.  Or perhaps I misunderstood the question.  The first date though looked `normal` got a dip in `R_10Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a data frame of differences `diff` by rows using `apply`. We have to transpose `t()` the result to get back data in a long format. Then get a vector of rows where all the `diff` are positive. These correspond to normal curves.

```
d_diff <- t(apply(FedYieldCurve, 1, diff)) #difference in yield by maturity
incr <- apply(d_diff, 1, function(x) all(x > 0, na.rm=TRUE)) #all increasing yield
decr <- apply(d_diff, 1, function(x) all(x < 0, na.rm=TRUE)) #all decreasing yield

normal <-FedYieldCurve[incr,]
inverse <-FedYieldCurve[decr,]
humped <-FedYieldCurve[!incr&!decr,]# not incr and not decr
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much, is a very accurate solution.

Comment: in practice, it doesn't have to decrease at every maturity to be considered inverted.  Notice that `inverse` has zero rows, but most people would call the curve inverted in parts of 2006 and 2007.  @Sogomon, I think it might be better to pick 3 spots on the curve (e.g. 2s, 5s, 10s) so you can define it like: inverted=2s > 5s & 5s > 10s, normal=2s < 5s & 5s < 10s, humped=sign(2s-5s)!=sign(5s-10s).